# Property is missing in type but required in type

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to implement simple event dispatcher on TypeScript.

My custom types are declared like this:

`events.d.ts`:

```
type AppEvent = { [key: string]: any }

type AppEventListener<T> = <T extends AppEvent>(event: T) => void;
```

When I pass any object in this function

```
   public addListener<T extends AppEvent>(event: T, listener: AppEventListener<T>)
```

I get the following error:

```
Argument of type '(event: TestEvent) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AppEventListener<typeof TestEvent>'.
   Types of parameters 'event' and 'event' are incompatible.
     Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'TestEvent'.
       Property 'name' is missing in type 'AppEvent' but required in type 'TestEvent'.
```

So, this type `AppEvent` cannot have any additional properties. How to make it work? Any help appreciated.

Full code example:

```
class EventDispatcher {
  private listeners: Map<AppEvent, Array<AppEventListener<AppEvent>>>

  constructor() {
    this.listeners = new Map();
  }

  public dispatch<T extends AppEvent>(event: T): void {
    const listeners = this.listeners.get(event.constructor);
    if (listeners) {
      listeners.forEach((callback) => {
        callback(event);
      });
    }
  }

  public addListener<T extends AppEvent>(event: T, listener: AppEventListener<T>): void {
    let listeners = this.listeners.get(event);
    if (!listeners) {
      listeners = [listener];
      this.listeners.set(event, listeners);
    } else {
      listeners.push(listener);
    }
  }
}

class TestEvent {
  public name: string = ''
}

const dispatcher = new EventDispatcher();
const listener = (event: TestEvent) => {
  console.dir(event);
};
dispatcher.addListener(TestEvent, listener);

const event = new TestEvent('name');
dispatcher.dispatch(event);
```

Comment: First of all, `type AppEventListener<T> = <T extends AppEvent>(event: T) => void;` isn't right. You have two different `T`'s there. You probably want either `type AppEventListener<T extends AppEvent> = (event: T) => void;` or `type AppEventListener = <T extends AppEvent>(event: T) => void;`.

Comment: Thank you. First variant is preferable then because it allows to require the same type for both arguments in `addListener` method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you should make `AppEventLister` a generic type referring to a non-generic function, like this:

```
type AppEventListener<T> = (event: T) => void;
```

You're saying "an `AppEventListener<T>` will take an event of type `T`".  That's what you want, right?

---

Your original definition was a generic type referring to a generic function, with two different generic parameters of the same name, equivalent to

```
type AppEventListenerBad<T> = <U>(event: U) => void;
```

(the rename doesn't change the type; it just makes makes more clear what was happening with type parameter name shadowing) meaning "an `AppEventListener<T>` will ignore `T` entirely and take an event of any type `U` that the caller wants to specify", which is unlikely what you mean.  And that's where your error is coming from: `(event: TestEvent) => void` is not assignable to `<U>(event: U) => void`.

---

Once you do this, a lot of other issues are solved, but they might bring up other problems.  A major one is that the [standard library typings for `Map`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.9.6/lib/lib.es2015.collection.d.ts#L21-L29) represent a very basic mapping from keys of type `K` to values of type `V`.  It does not have a way to say that keys of certain subtypes of `K` map to values of programmatically determined subtypes of `V`.  In your case you could make a new interface for the way you are using `Map`:

```
interface AppEventListenerMap {
  get<T>(x: T): Array<AppEventListener<T>> | undefined;
  set<T>(x: T, val: Array<AppEventListener<T>>): void;
}
```

And then in `EventDispatcher` you make the `listeners` property a value of type `AppEventListenerMap`:

```
class EventDispatcher {
  private listeners: AppEventListenerMap;

  constructor() {
    this.listeners = new Map();
  }
```

That will mostly make your code example work, except for the fact that you seem to be using `event` as the key sometimes, and using `event.constructor` as the key other times.  That inconsistency seems wrong, and you probably need to decide exactly the type relationship to get it working properly.

Anyway, hopefully this helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAsAFBJKiSwLIBCGA9vANYDidARplHkSSQC4CeMZAEEYMAKIA3CMF5IAvHiQBtBhH4AuJFF4AnAJbAA5gF0tIYPyQBfbjwFCkoidNkAZfTpkRdAHgAqAHwKSAAUEK68Wv4AlArBkrT6ACYA3ER2JIa8PgBmlE5iUjK8Hl7APgCyIDBcxDwkRhC8AYGhAB7RMVrCurog-L7Oxe6eORV+QcEAPkgArsDJELmGEGmZPFDNrR3RADRIkpg9fQNDRZFl4z6tgd2HSev1JLaEG-AYIFCcI7wAIp44Lx4AALHx1BokGAGI45JAYMbeXRQHoXEpXJHVGDpN7PHjwWjAHS6ObwXi0XShOIEPENXggzwAOgR5R8nEUFQA7kgsVScZCbBlaUgYHNWAj4EhkoCQMCQQEkBB2uNkpxhpE2hESl0tIkUhCBUgCUS5CzrsiQvSmWakVBGU1eOFIjF+Yb9LkwjaJlBqRsBV62YzchTxAgQaFQugMBh2Iw4vJgjTDZCozGEAwnSUXX7IdZs8KXjnXjnReL9JKQMlkhiJgqlSq1WjZJrIvt4YiJqiXOiOzcgvc9ckDf7mu3WRbFFa7QHkfbmpnZPnk+6wgBCGc+4eGjchZQzkyu5NT5m92dbR1a2QHDdLw3WRUYLZb-2nu2iqDhme3gWvH8bYt4h8XycP40C8L8z4imKEqkOAEBaMShhGCEADkKH-kKDTGjoUoynK4IchA3K-ACFD4ZS35GoSOEziEC5REgoE6L88aJjm2G0BgECMtKlKXrwlHWIeuFkaCPiMpW1anqETHgZE16nvm7zUXI-EhFyjFgb8fIbNKolgroPF4aC9G3q81hAA)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now I understand generics much better.
Using `event` and `event.constructor` - it was the idea to register listeners by event type (class name) and then dispatch event using object of this class. It works if I get listeners by `event.constructor`, if i just pass object instance there, it won't work